# Good book or guide for Debian packaging using Bazaar and Ubuntu Distributed Development

Tags: packaging, documentation

It seems that Ubuntu provide several tools to help you building Debian packages with the bazaar version control.

So far I just found online documentation, but I personally prefer to learn from books.  I am also interested in learning the *Launchpad* workflow. Could you recommend some book about those topics?

Comment: Also, define "Launchpad Workflow".  That is ambiguous, as there are multiple workflows for Ubuntu, and there isn't one "Launchpad Workflow".

Comment: I meant the main idea about how to use Launchpad. This is, how the upstream works and how people accept pull request and so on...

Comment: There's no books documenting those workflows, you may want to read the Launchpad help documentation, though.  That's a completely separate process from Packaging, though, so it might deserve its own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "book" on Debian Packaging or Ubuntu Packaging that follows all the packaging policies for both, that is up to date, as there are changes frequently enough that you have to read the policies and the guides after they're updated.  There's only the guides for Ubuntu or Debian.  I had been looking for books for some time, but in fact there were none that were 'good' enough to meet what is needed here.

[The Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/) was modified since I first read it to use `bzr` and version control systems (i.e. Ubuntu Distributed Development, or UDD) for packaging.  That will be your best resource.

---

**Ubuntu**: Use the packaging guide link above.  It touches upon using Bazaar (`bzr`) and version control for packaging in Ubuntu, using the UDD process.

**Debian**: The [Debian New Maintainers Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) may be a good start point.  This does not use bzr for version controls, since that's an almost Ubuntu-specific thing.

Comment: Note that I, for nginx packaging, use half UDD and half traditional packaging - I use UDD for the diffing and merging, but I end up submitting debdiffs or uploading directly since I have upload rights.